# Check if an object has a singleton class

Tags: ruby, singleton

I am writing a module with method `foo`, which calls a class method `bar` on the receiver's class. My current approach is to use `self.class.bar`, which works fine unless the class method is defined in an instance class instead of a "real" one:

```
module M
  def foo
    self.class.bar
  end
end

obj = Object.new
class << obj
  include M
  def self.bar
    42
  end
end

obj.foo # => NoMethodError: undefined method `bar' for Object:Class
```

This makes sense because `obj.class` does not return singleton classes. I **could** use `obj.singleton_class` instead, and everything would run smoothly:

```
module M
  def foo
    self.singleton_class.bar
  end
end

obj = Object.new
class << obj
  include M
  def self.bar
    42
  end
end

obj.foo # => 42
```

only if the method is defined on a singleton class for the same reason as above. Worse still, it creates a new singleton class for every receiver, something I want to avoid as these might be a fair amount of objects. So instead, I want some way to retrieve an object's singleton class **if and only if** it is already defined, i.e. something of the type `obj.has_singleton_class ? obj.singleton_class : obj.class`. I couldn't find any way to perform this check though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every object always has a singleton class in Ruby. The specific implementation you use (MRI, YARV, Rubinius, JRuby, IronRuby, MacRuby, MagLev, MRuby, etc.) may or may not optimize memory usage by not allocating memory for a singleton class that isn't used, but that's a private internal implementation detail, an invisible transparent compiler optimization. Whenever you go looking for a singleton class, it'll be there.

Well, actually, that's not *quite* true. Immediate values, i.e. `Integer`s, `Symbol`s and `Float`s *cannot* have singleton classes.

So, those three will *never* have a singleton class, all others *always* have a singleton class.

Comment: This answer needed an update, since `Fixnum` is deprecated in Ruby 2.4. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21411269/513951) by @JörgWMittag ;)