# What is the difference between Integer and Fixnum?

Tags: ruby

I know that the `Fixnum` class inherits from the `Integer` class. But what is the actual difference between them? Are there any use cases where we sometimes use `Fixnum`, and sometimes use `Integer` instead?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You never "use" `Integer`. It is an abstract class whose job is to endow its children (`Fixnum` and `Bignum`) with methods. Under effectively no circumstances will you ever ask for an object's class and be told that it is an `Integer`.

Comment: This answer was correct for Ruby 2.3 and older versions. It is wrong as of Ruby 2.4. See the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21372649/what-is-the-difference-between-integer-and-fixnum/21411269#21411269).

Comment: @matt when you say "You never "use" `Integer`.  It is an abstract class whose job is to endow its children (`Fixnum` and `Bignum`) with methods", is it the same as: `Integer` is an abstract class that defines the interface for its subclasses `Fixnum` and `Bignum` and you never instantiate using an abstract class?

Answer (score 89):

**UPDATE**: As of Ruby 2.4, the `Fixnum` and `Bignum` classes are gone, there is only `Integer`. The exact same optimizations still exist, but they are treated as "proper" compiler optimizations, i.e. behind the scenes, invisible to the programmer.

---

This is somewhat confusing. `Integer` is the *real* class that you should think about. `Fixnum` is basically a performance optimization that should never have been made visible to the programmer in the first place. (Compare this with flonums in YARV, which are implemented entirely as an optimization inside the VM, and never exposed to the programmer.)

Basically, `Fixnum`s are fast and `Bignum`s are slow(er), and the implementation automatically switches back and forth between them. You never ask for one of those directly, you will just get one or the other, depending on whether your integer fits into the restricted size of a `Fixnum` or not.

Comment: So if you want to implement something like `3.to_roman`, you should extend `Integer` and not `Fixnum` right?

Comment: Doing so would make `to_roman` available to both `Fixnum` and `Bignum`. If that's your goal, then yes.

Comment: It's not really clear whether you and @matt contradict each other about the pre-"Ruby 2.4" state of affairs.